# Scheme returns #<procedure>, not a value

Tags: scheme

I am trying to use the unrestricted lambda in order to apply an arbitrary number of procedures on one argument. My code returns '#procedure' rather than a value (I was expecting ((compose-many add1 add1 add1) 3) => 6). Please clarify my mistake. Thank you.

```
(define compose-many
  (lambda args
    (lambda (x) 
      (cond
       ((null? args)
        x)
       ((null? (cdr args))
        (car args) x)
       (else (car args) (compose-many (cdr args)))))))

((compose-many add1 add1 add1) 3)
```

Comment: Minor comment: we don't need a separate case for handling a single-element args list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you call the recursion you're expected to again pass values to the parameters in `(lambda args (lambda (x) ...))`, when the correct would be to just iterate over the args. Also, you forgot to actually *apply* the procedures! An expression like this: `((null? (cdr args)) (car args) x)` *ignores* the result of `(car args)` and just returns `x`.

To see this more clearly, let's see how the solution should look for a case in particular, say - we only have to compose three procedures. Notice that we return a single `lambda` and how the procedures are applied:

```
(define (compose f g h)
  (lambda (x)
    (f (g (h x)))))
```

We should approach the problem differently: we must return the `(lambda (x) ...)` only once, and a "loop" should process the args list before returning it. Something like this, perhaps?

```
(define compose-many
  (lambda args
    ; we return (lambda (x) ...) only once, is not part of the recursion
    (lambda (x)
      ; here we loop over the args list
      (define (helper args)
        (if (null? args)
            x
            ; notice the "((" here we apply the procedure!
            ((car args) (helper (cdr args)))))
      ; call the helper a single time and we're done!
      (helper args))))

((compose-many add1 add1 add1) 3)
=> 6
```